# How to inject HttpServletRequest inside of JAX-RS ClientRequestFilter?

Tags: filter, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I have written a JAX-RS Client libary which i will be used in different JavaEE WebApps.
These WebApps are providing JAX-RS Endpoints.

I want to passthrough a session attribute as header param for all requests, but the HttpServletRequest is always null.

```
@PreMatching
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR)
public class JwtTokenClientFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String jwtToken = (String) servletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("jwt_token");
        requestContext.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
    }

}
```

How to inject HttpServletRequest inside of JAX-RS ClientRequestFilter?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:

Is this maybe a solution, or am i running into some trouble?
Will it work with many request from diffrent users?

```
/* my server webservice*/
@Path("/autos")
public class CarResource extends MyJaxRsConfig {

    @Inject
    private CarStatsClient CarStatsClient;

    @GET
    @RolesAllowed("car_admin")
    @Path("{carNo}/stats")
    public Response getCarStats(@Valid @NotNull @PathParam("carNo") String carNo) {
        return CarStatsClient.getCarStats(carNo);
    }

}


/* my client libary*/

//@ApplicationScoped
@RequestScoped
public class CarStatsService implements Serializable, CarStatsClient {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    public static final String RESOURCE_PATH_CAR_STATS = "{carNo}/stats";

    @Inject
    private JwtTokenClientFilter jwt;

    @Inject
    @TargetUri(SERVER + "/api/v2/" + CarStatsService.RESOURCE_PATH_CAR_STATS)
    private WebTarget carStatsTarget;

    @Override
    //public Response getCarStats(String jwtToken, String carNo) {
    public Response getCarStats(String carNo) {
        carStatsTarget.register(jwt); //TODO: create Annotation
        Response response = carStatsTarget.resolveTemplate("carNo", carNo).request()
                /* .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken) */
                .get();
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            logger.warning("->CarStatsService->getCarProfitStats()");
        }
        return response;
    }

}

/*  client libary too*/
@RequestScoped
@PreMatching
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR)
public class JwtTokenClientFilter implements ClientRequestFilter, ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String jwtToken = (String) servletRequest.getSession().getAttribute("jwt_token");
        requestContext.getHeaders().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwtToken);
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a _client_ side filter. There _is_ no HttpServletRequest on the client side. This is server side object. The HttpSession is also an server side object. The session is maintained from server to client with the use of a JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: The client is used by my jaxrs rest server to call another webservices.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The injection system used for the client and the server will be different. You will need to somehow pass the HttpServletRequest from the server (where ever you are using it) into the client.

Comment: In other words, the client has no idea it being used on the server side; it is oblivious to anything that has to with the server.

Comment: Is it possible to make it to an server side object, maybe also implements ``ClientRequestFilter, ContainerRequestFilter`` ? Or do you have any advise to passthrough the attribute in a modular way?

Comment: You would need to tap into the injection system and bind the client filter into it. I only know how to do that with Jersey.

Comment: My Application Server is using a Jersey.